# Subscript error when trying to save/preview notebook

Tags: r, rstudio, subscript

EDIT: It seems as though RStudio Preview version 0.99.1285 has issues with notebooks and rMarkdown documents. An install of the standard RStudio is able to knit the same code. Thanks everyone for the time and effort.

I'm trying to create a simple R notebook in order to generate readable analysis reports. However whenever I try to run my notebook I get a subscript out of bounds error that I haven't been able to diagnose and resolve.

I've updated all my packages and recreated similar code but I get the same error.

The R Markdown code (library(dplyr) loaded in global environment)
edit: added library(dplyr) in first chunk

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

```{r}
library(dplyr)
```


```{r}
adataframe<-data_frame(a=rnorm(160),
                       b=rnorm(160,mean=5,sd=10),
                       c=sample(1:100,160,replace=TRUE),
                       z=sample(1:100,160,replace=TRUE),
                       letter=rep(c("w","x","y","z"),40))
```

test test min z is `r min(adataframe$z)` to max z at `r max(adataframe$z)`

```{r}
adataframe %>%
  select(letter,z,b,a) %>% 
  group_by(letter) %>%
  summarise_all(sum) %>% 
  mutate(division1=z/b,division2=b/a)
```
````

If I preview the document without running the chunks, the document displays as expected.

However If I run all the code chunks and try to preview the document I get this following error:

```
Quitting from lines 7-8 (test.Rmd) 
Error in csvs[[i + 1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Which corresponds with the first code chunk.

This is a test notebook in a new project and as such has no other objects in the Global Environment other than "adataframe".

Thanks for reading.

Comment: rmarkdown documents are compiled in a separate R session, not in your current R session, so you need `library(dplyr)` before using `dplyr` functions.

Comment: As @eipi10 noted, you need to add `library(dplyr)`.  I could not reproduce your error after I did that.  The script was processed with no errors and with the expected output.

Comment: When I add library(dplyr), I get the subscript error in that new chunk:

Comment: I'm not getting error when I run your code.

Comment: More detail - if I preview the document before I run all the chunks the document displays as expected. However if I run all the chunks, I get the csvs[[i+1]]:subscript out of bounds error. Is this normal behaviour for rmarkdown documents?

Answer (score 0):

What version of the RStudio preview release are you running? I believe this was a bug in one of the RStudio builds that should now be resolved (at least from v0.99.1283).

Comment: It seems as if my RStudio is a little older than that (v0.99.1249). Unfortunately the "Check for updates" selection tells me I have the most recent package. I'll try updating manually.